# How to delete all partitions and re-install latests Ubuntu version?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-18.04

Hope you are all doing fine.
First of all, I am not an expert on Linux or computer crafts.

Now, to the point:
I have an old Dell Vostro3500 laptop.
It has a partition that allows selecting between windows07 and Ubuntu16.04.
I want to delete the windows partition (or both, if simpler) and install the latest Ubuntu version on the computer (clean).

I know I can upgrade Ubuntu from "upgrade manager", however, I would like to do a fresh install of ubuntu. Ultimately, what I want is to make space for ubuntu (by deleting windows, which I don't use) and have a clean nice start with the latest ubuntu version.

If someone can give me a simple "step-by-step tutorial on how to achieve these two things (deleting windows/and ubuntu and reinstalling Ubuntu), I would be very grateful.

Basically:

1. How to delete windows or both windows and ubuntu?.
2. How to install Ubuntu on a free operating system computer?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. You can create a booting device (USB or DVD or whatever) then select the scaring format all the HDD when it will be required. OR, you may start from Linux then enter in partition editor (gpart) delete the windows partition, enlarge the Ubuntu one (since is a partition on which the system is running a reboot it will be required. The 1st solution is the safer one (it allows alwats to have a system from which you can start, the USB or DVD used to install) HNY.

Comment: This is a [link](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-ubuntu-20-04) about a stable Long Term version installation step by step...

Comment: thank you very much @Hastur, Can you point me in the direction of a link or a reliable page that explains how to create a booting Ubuntu USB?. I really don't want to mess things up!. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok  @Hastur I will check that link!

Comment: HI @Hastur I am sorry for my ignorance, but on the link you mentioned, I don't understand what to do on: Option 1: Create a Bootable USB Drive on Ubuntu->
->Use the Create startup disk tool: ->Open a search dialog, and type create startup. what is a search dialog, or at least, where do I open it?. Sorry again

Comment: You're welcome. Never excuse for what you do not know, only if you do not want to learn (IMO). Btw from that [link](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-ubuntu-20-04) (try to read it all) you may read 1) download the material 2) Create the USB that is able to boot 3) Reboot the computer starting from this USB 4) run Ubuntu 5) install Ubuntu (Choose keyboard etc etc ) then   __"you can wipe the hard drive clean prior to installing Ubuntu by clicking Erase disk and install Ubuntu."__ ... cross finger and wait. HNY This if you have a USB...

Comment: IMHO you really should reach out to your local Linux Users group or similar.  There is a lot of gotchas and difficult to accurately advise on a general forum.  One way to do this is to create a linux boot disk with the appropriate version of Linux, then to overwrite the first 4k of your hard drive/ssd  with Zeros which effectively blanks out the disk.  There are a few gotchas though - like finding the appropriate hard drive device (and dealing with UEFI if you are using UEFI booting - although I don't believe this is an issue on a Vostro 3500 as it does not support that standard)